# Fixing a complex linear constraint in pyomo

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraint, pyomo

My directed graph *f* with any node *u* has a set of outgoing and incoming links as *uv ∈ O(u)* and *vu ∈ I(u)* respectively.
I am trying to write this constraint[image: structural constraint]

here *ϕ* refers to a binary decision variable while *u_bar, v_bar* and *uv_bar* refers to nodes and link in another graph.
I am trying to model it this way.

```
#Dictionary of Node as key with its outgoing edges as value pair
out_edges_node_map = {}
for out_going in G_SERVER.nodes:
    out_new_item = {out_going: list(G_SERVER.out_edges(out_going))}
    out_edges_node_map.update(out_new_item)
print("Testing to print dictionary", out_edges_node_map)   

#list of list where index is node and list elements are destinations of the outgoing edge of that node
    out_main_list = []
    for out_index_list, out_value_list in out_edges_node_map.items():
        out_list = []
        for i in out_value_list:
            out_list.append(int(i[1]))
        out_main_list.append(out_list)
    print("printing the list of list for all nodes and their destinations in the out going edges", out_main_list)  

model.capacity_BW_out=Param(model.capacity_BW_set, initialize=out_main_list)

#Dictionary of Node as key with its incoming edges as value pair
    in_edges_node_map = {}
    for in_coming in G_SERVER.nodes:
        in_new_item = {in_coming: list(G_SERVER.in_edges(in_coming))}
        in_edges_node_map.update(in_new_item)
    print("Testing to print incoming dictionary", in_edges_node_map)

#list of list where index is node and list elements are destinations of incoming edge of that node
    in_main_list = []
    for in_index_list, in_value_list in in_edges_node_map.items():
        in_list = []
        for i in in_value_list:
            in_list.append(int(i[0]))
        in_main_list.append(in_list)
    print("printing the list of list for all nodes and their destinations in the in coming edges", in_main_list)

model.capacity_BW_in=Param(model.capacity_BW_set, initialize=in_main_list)

model.out_going_link_u_set=RangeSet(0, len(in_edges_node_map)-1)
model.in_coming_link_u_set=RangeSet(0, len(out_edges_node_map)-1)

model.out_going_destination_u_set=RangeSet(0, len(in_main_list)-1)
model.in_going_destination_u_set=RangeSet(0, len(out_main_list)-1)
 
def structural_rule1(model, u, uvb, ub, vb):
    return sum(model.fil[uvb, uv] for uv in model.out_going_link_u_set) - sum(
        model.fil[uvb, vu] for vu in model.in_coming_link_u_set) <= model.fi[ub, u] - model.fi[vb, u]

model.structural_constraint1 = Constraint(model.out_going_destination_u_set, model.demand_BW_set, model.demand_CPU_set, model.demand_CPU_set, rule=structural_rule1)
```

Pyomo is asking me to define *ub and vb* (from right side of constriant) Where I should define these? I have tried passing that as arguments and defining these on right side as well.

Answer (score 2):

Names you use should be defined somewhere, either as arguments of the function, or as elements of some set you are iterating/summing over. In this case you havent defined *ub* and *uv* anywhere. You can fix this by adding them as arguments of your constraint function and specifying the proper indexsets when adding the constraint to the model.

Comment: I appreciate the prompt response but unfortunately, I did the same before posting the question here. Besides this, even though I make the right side = 1 still this equation is not working.