# Looking for correction in pyomo constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraint, pyomo

I am working on two graphs having nodes and edges.
Graph1: VNF Graph with node demand and bandwidth demand.
Graph2: Server Graph with node capacity and bandwidth capacity.

The nodes and links of graph1 can be optimally mapped on graph 2 when the demanded resources ≤ capacity. I have written and executed that successfully.

Right now, I am trying to write the following constraint.

[image: this constraint]

Here

uv∈O(u)     = outgoing links of any node (u) in the SERVER graph

Φf          = Decision Variable referring to mapping of nodes and links

uv BAR      = link in VNF graph

uv∈I(u)     = incoming links of any node (u) in the SERVER graph

uBAR,vBAR   = any node in VNF graph

u           = node in SERVER graph

My minimal code to do so is:

```
#Graph Reading
def SERVER_graph():  # SERVER Graph with few nodes
    SERVER = nx.DiGraph()
    SERVER.add_nodes_from([("S1", {"C_CPU": 10}),
                           ("S2", {"C_CPU": 20}),
                           ("S3", {"C_CPU": 30})])
    SERVER.add_edge("S1", "S2", bw_capacity=50)
    SERVER.add_edge("S2", "S1", bw_capacity=50)
    SERVER.add_edge("S2", "S3", bw_capacity=70)
    SERVER.add_edge("S3", "S2", bw_capacity=70)
    SERVER.add_edge("S3", "S1", bw_capacity=60)
    SERVER.add_edge("S1", "S3", bw_capacity=60)
    return SERVER
SERVER_graph()
def VNF_graph():  # VNF Graph with few nodes and links
    VNF = nx.DiGraph()
    VNF.add_nodes_from([("VNF1", {"D_CPU": 10}),
                        ("VNF2", {"D_CPU": 5}),
                        ("VNF3", {"D_CPU": 10}),
                        ("VNF4", {"D_CPU": 5}),
                        ("VNF5", {"D_CPU": 5})])

    VNF.add_edge("VNF1", "VNF2", bw_demand=20)
    VNF.add_edge("VNF2", "VNF3", bw_demand=20)
    VNF.add_edge("VNF3", "VNF4", bw_demand=10)
    VNF.add_edge("VNF5", "VNF4", bw_demand=5)
    VNF.add_edge("VNF1", "VNF3", bw_demand=30)
    VNF.add_edge("VNF2", "VNF5", bw_demand=40)
    return VNF
VNF_graph()
enter code here
def mymodel():
model = ConcreteModel() # Model Creation

my_VNF_graph=VNF_graph()
my_SERVER_graph=SERVER_graph()

D_CPU = []  # List for extracting the CPU and BW demands from VNFs
for Dcpunode in my_VNF_graph.nodes:
    D_CPU.append(my_VNF_graph.nodes[Dcpunode]["D_CPU"])
D_BW = []
for Dbwlink in my_VNF_graph.edges:
    D_BW.append(my_VNF_graph.edges[Dbwlink]["bw_demand"])

C_CPU = []  # List for extracting the CPU and BW capacity from SERVER
for Ccpunode in my_SERVER_graph.nodes:
    C_CPU.append(my_SERVER_graph.nodes[Ccpunode]["C_CPU"])
C_BW = []
for Cbwlink in my_SERVER_graph.edges:
    C_BW.append(my_SERVER_graph.edges[Cbwlink]["bw_capacity"])

model.demand_CPU_set = RangeSet(0, len(D_CPU)-1) # define the set of parameters
model.demand_BW_set = RangeSet(0, len(D_BW)-1)
model.capacity_CPU_set = RangeSet(0, len(C_CPU)-1)
model.capacity_BW_set = RangeSet(0, len(C_BW)-1)

#model decision variables using the set definitions
model.fi=Var(model.demand_CPU_set, model.capacity_CPU_set, within=Binary) #for node
model.fil=Var(model.demand_BW_set, model.capacity_BW_set, within=Binary) #for link

#Structural constraint for link mapping
out_edge_list=list(my_SERVER_graph.out_edges)
in_edge_list = list(my_SERVER_graph.in_edges)

model.out_link_set=Set(initialize=(out_edge_list[i] for i in range(len(out_edge_list))), dimen=2)
model.in_link_set=Set(initialize=(in_edge_list[i] for i in range(len(in_edge_list))), dimen=2)

def structural_rule1 (model, u, uvb):
    return sum(model.fil[uvb, uv] for uv in model.out_link_set)- sum(model.fil[uvb, vu] for vu in model.in_link_set )==model.fi[ub, u]-model.fi[vb, u]
model.structural_constraint1=Constraint(model.capacity_CPU_set, model.demand_BW_set, rule=structural_rule1)
```

Comment: Seems related:  [Fixing a complex linear constraint in pyomo](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/9107/491)

Comment: @SecretAgentMan That solution didn't work for me. Regards